# How to remove text from a field

Tags: acumatica

In the SO Invoice report, I add a link from ARTran to FSAppointment.  This is done in order to include FSappointment.LongDescr in the report.  A request, is to remove the text 'Internal Notes' PLUS all text following the string.  I notice a red error message printed in the report output, in the cases where 'Internal Notes' string is not included in LongDescr.  I tried several permutations but have not found a resolution.
Here is my formula

```
=IIf(InStr([FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText],'Internal Notes')>0,
Left( [FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText], InStr([FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText],'Internal Notes') )
,[FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText])
```

Note that I created a non-bound field DescriptionAsPlainText, in order to apply pretty formatting, for LongDescr field.

Here is the error message:
**An error has occurred while the Left(Identifier(FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText), InStr(Identifier(FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText), Const(Internal Notes))) function was being executed:
'Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length'**

Comment: How are you populating this unbound field? Are you using PXDBScalar or PXDBCalced attributed? If not can you try using one of these attributes to populate your field and then use it on a Formula on Report Designer?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code fails if the value of [FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText] is null.  Add an IIF([FSAppointment.DescriptionAsPlainText]=null, clause around your existing code to exit in case of null.